# is it possible to load EF metadata at runtime?

Tags: entity-framework, runtime, metadata

I want to load EF metadata from database at runtime. Is that scenario possible? First get the data from database, then write it to .ssdl, .msl and .csdl files sounds ok. But how to tell EF to use what I've loaded? Do I need to compile it or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

New up a `MetadataWorkspace` using the [constructor which takes these files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679683(v=VS.100).aspx).

Then you can new up an `EntityConnection` passing the `MetadataWorkspace` to the overloaded constructor, and finally new the `ObjectContext` passing that.

With all that said, I wonder if this is the best approach to your problem.