# How to get the MaxLength from a Fluent API mapping specification in runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-5, fluent-interface, maxlength

I need to retrieve the maxlength value specified for a field using Fluent API and Entity Framework 5 Code First.

I have seen a couple of examples using MetadataWorkspace but it doesn't work when you use Fluent API.
For instance, I tried this code but the value for MaxLenght is always null:

```
ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<GlobalItem>(typeof(TEntity).FullName, DataSpace.OSpace).MetadataProperties[field].TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value
```

Inside the Fluent API configuration file I have the following code for the necessary properties:

```
Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(50);
```

I know the mapping is working because if I try to save the object with more than 50 characters in that field it fails.

I just need guidance for getting the maxlenght value but to give some perspective the goal is:

1. Create new Foo object
2. Get the maxlength value defined for Bar property using Fluent API.
3. Apply certain rules based on the maxlength to the string to be assigned to Bar.
4. Save.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want us to write it for you???

Comment: That wont be necessary, I just need guidance on what library can I use to get the maxlength value, the code is already done except for that part. I just edited the question to make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: `but it doesn't work when you use Fluent API.`  what doesnt work ?

Comment: @philsoady, I edited the question to clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the facet was declared ? Show matching api config

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9580743/1347784

Comment: @philsoady, I updated the question. From what i see in other posts that works ok if you use annotations but not fluent api to specify the maxlength validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the storage model. Check docu on the Enum DataSpace
Use The `EntityType` items.

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void EFToolsTest() {

        var context = new BosMasterDbContext("MYDBCONTEXT");
        ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        var xyz = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);
        foreach (var ET in xyz) {
            foreach (var sp in ET.Properties) {
                Debug.WriteLine(sp.Name + ":" + sp.MaxLength);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I may have a different version (using EF 5.0) but I have to use (sp.TypeUsage.Facets.Contains("MaxLength") ? sp.TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value : string.Empty) to get the MaxLength. The compiler won't accept "sp.MaxLength".

Comment: This answer has is problematic with the future of entity framework dropping the object context.